# Two random terms with nlme

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I am performing a mixed model with `nlme` package in R. My situation is:
The mixed model is:

```
MY = DFC + DFC2, random=~DFC|Animal, data=my_data)
```

where `Animal` is the random effect. 
However, if I write the model like this, I can only obtain random intercept, and slope for `DFC` (by `Animal`), but not `DFC2`. 
I would like to have also the random slope (by `Animal`) for `DFC2`!
Could you please help me?

Thank you very much,

Comment: have you tried `random=~DFC+DFC2|Animal` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the library lme4

```
    library(lme4)
    fit <- lmer(y ~ x1 + x2 (1+ x1 + x2|group), data = test.df) 
    coef(fit)
```

Use coef() on your fitted object to see the slopes.

Comment: this doesn't answer the OP's question -- they apparently have two continuous predictors and would like random effects on both of them.  In `lme4` this would be `lmer(y~x+x2+(1+x+x2|group), ...)` (but the OP asked about `nlme`)

Comment: It works by the way of Ben Bolker. Thank you very much!